# Se puede usar los styles de Ionic 2 material design en Ionic 1 ?

Tags: angularjs, css, ionic, programación-móvil

me gustaría saber como usar el material design de Ionic 2, pero que también los estilos que utiliza para IOS, ya que existe un plugin para hacer material design Ionic 1 pero es solo con los estilos que para Ionic2 se usan solo para android.

Alguien conoce algún plugin que sea material design pero que sea diferente para IOS como para Android? Gracias.

Comment: A que plugin te refieres?

Comment: http://ionicmaterial.com/  Lo que yo busco es tenes los mismos estilos y animaciones que por default vienen en Ionic 2, que se diferencian según en que sistema operativo se corra la aplicación.

Comment: Ok, creo que debes recordar que Material Design es hecho por Google y IOS es hecho por Apple así que por supuesto tendrás dos estilos diferentes en las dos plataformas. El propósito del plugin es darte un sólo estilo para tu app mientras que el de Ionic en cualquier versión es darte un estilo de acuerdo a la plataforma para parecer lo mas nativo posible. Partiendo de ahí no me parece que lo que quieres sea posible.

Comment: Claro, por eso buscaba alguna opción que provea material design de google para android y el diseño de Apple con su experiencia de usuario para IOS. Que a esto sí lo tiene Ionic 2, pero queria saber existe alfuna forma de hacerlo para la version 1.